# How do I migrate this GKVoiceChat code to Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

I would like to migrate the following code that creates a Game Center `GKVoiceChat` into Swift:

```
GKMatch* match;
GKVoiceChat *teamChannel = [[match voiceChatWithName:@"redTeam"] retain];
GKVoiceChat *allChannel = [[match voiceChatWithName:@"allPlayers"] retain];
```

I suspect the Swift code looks something like this:

```
var match: GKMatch!
func voiceChatWithName(name: String!) -> GKVoiceChat! {
    return nil
}
```

But even though I searched through the documentation I don't exactly know how it works in Swift. How do I migrate the code above to Swift?

Comment: The `match` variable in your first code snippet doesn't have a value - so your calls to `voiceChatWithName` won't do anything because `match` is nil. In your actual code, where does `match` come from?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have just updated my question including the declaration of the variable `match: GKMatch`. Is there anything else to add? The Objective-C code looks like a declaration, while the code translated in Swift is a method, isn't it? I am actually looking at a way to migrate `voiceChatWithName ` into Swift, but I couldn't find any. Thanks!

Comment: Hi - my question was actually regarding your objective-c code. You have `GKMatch* match;`, but this just declares an empty variable with no value (so the lines afterwards won't have any effect). Are you using a `GKMatchmaker` or something similar to get a `match` object?

Comment: Yes, I am using something similar to handle a match when a sufficient number of `GKPlayers` has been found: `func matchmakerViewController(viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController!,
        didFindMatch match: GKMatch!) {...}`. Thanks again for your help, @James!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in your `GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate` method, you should just be able to do something like the following:

```
func matchmakerViewController(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController!,
                      didFindMatch match: GKMatch!) {

    let teamChannel = match.voiceChatWithName("redTeam")
    let allChannel = match.voiceChatWithName("allPlayers")

    // use the channels above
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Did you mean `GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate ` or `GKMatchmakerViewController`?

Comment: You said in your comment that you've implemented `matchmakerViewController(didFindMatch:)`? You should be able to call `voiceChatWithName("Example")` on the match that you use in that method.

Comment: Sure, I said that. I was just asking if the method I mentioned in my comment is actually called `GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate` or `GKMatchmakerViewController`. Please take a look at my suggested edit. Anyway, that doesn't really matter. Thanks again for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: The _method_, `matchmakerViewController(didFindMatch:)` is _implemented_ by a class that is a `GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate`. Typically, this will be the class that presents the `GKMatchmakerViewController`. The `GKMatchmakerViewController` then calls the `matchmakerViewController(didFindMatch:)` method on its delegate once it's found a match.